# read multiple uploaded files in c#

Tags: c#, file-upload

i am develop a project that can save and delete uploaded files from local system. here is the sample code and i am using fileupload asp-control in asp.net c#

```
List<AttachmentModel> attachmentList = new List<AttachmentModel>();

        if (fuAttachment.HasFiles)
        {
            foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in fuAttachment.PostedFiles)
            {
                attachment.AttachmentType = "Attachment";
                attachment.FileName = Path.GetFileName(fuAttachment.PostedFile.FileName);
                                   uploadedFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"~/Attachments/" + uploadedFile)));
                attachmentList.Add(attachment);
            }
        }
        objEL.AttachmentList = attachmentList;
```

i am trying to upload multiple files( >=2 files). but i am able to read only one file that is selected first..

so then i have changed one line

```
attachment.FileName = Path.GetFileName(fuAttachment.PostedFile.FileName);
```

to

```
attachment.FileName = uploadedFile.FileName;
```

but with this i am getting the whole path of the file as

> "C:\Users\ThirupathiReddy\Downloads\PSK_logo.jpg"

i just want to read the file name ...

thank you..

Comment: the use 1st one ``Path.GetFileName()``

Comment: but i am getting only one file to read.. how about to get the second if...??@EhsanSajjad

Comment: ``attachment.FileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName)``

Comment: had an error **“The given path's format is not supported.”** and changed the line **uploadedFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"~/Attachments/" + uploadedFile)));** 
to
**uploadedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Attachments/" + attachment.FileName));**

Comment: but still the attachmentlist contains two same file names.... @EhsanSajjad

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var fullFilename = @"C:\Users\ThirupathiReddy\Downloads\PSK_logo.jpg";
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(fullFilename );
var filename = fileInfo.Name;
```